# Cypher query aborts/stops and the memory consumption is not going down

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb

My query aborts with the memory limit exceeded. Memgraph keeps running, but even though the query was aborted, the memory isn't getting freed. How do I reset this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the `FREE MEMORY` query which tries to free unused memory chunks in different parts of the storage.